# "setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build" how to resolve this?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, arguments

Here is the full error message.

> The following assertion was thrown building MealDeatialRoute(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, _ModalScopeStatus]): setState() or
> markNeedsBuild() called during build.
>
> This MyApp widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the
> framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can
> be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of
> its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because
> the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a
> dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might
> not visit this widget during this build phase. The widget on which
> setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was: MyApp

And Here is a code of **main.**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './routes/main_tab_route.dart';
// import './routes/favorites_tab_route.dart';
// import './routes/filter_tab_route.dart';
import './routes/category_meal_route.dart';
import './routes/meal_detial_route.dart';
import './routes/select_filter_route.dart';

import './dummy_data.dart';
import './model/meal.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _filters = {
    'gluteenFree': false,
    'lactoseFree': false,
    'vegan': false,
    'vegetarian': false,
  };

  final List<Meal> _avialableMeal = dummyMeals;

  final List<Meal> _favoriteMeal = [];

  void _toggleFavorite(String id) {
    int existIndex = _favoriteMeal.indexWhere((meal) => meal.id == id);

    if (existIndex >= 0) {
      setState(() {
        _favoriteMeal.removeAt(existIndex);
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _favoriteMeal.add(dummyMeals.firstWhere((meal) => meal.id == id));
      });
    }
  }

  bool _isMealFavorite(String id) {
    return _favoriteMeal.any((meal) => meal.id == id);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Meal App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.red,
        colorScheme:
            ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(secondary: Colors.amberAccent),
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 23,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
          titleMedium: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MainTabRoute(_favoriteMeal),
        SelectFilterRoute.routeName: (context) => SelectFilterRoute(),
        CategoreyMealRoute.routeName: (context) => CategoreyMealRoute(),
        MealDeatialRoute.routeName: (context) =>
            MealDeatialRoute(_toggleFavorite, _isMealFavorite),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And an error is cause by **MealDeatailRoute.dart** file so which is below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/dummy_data.dart';

class MealDeatialRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/meal-detail';

  final Function toggleFavorite;
  final Function isFavorite;

  MealDeatialRoute(this.isFavorite, this.toggleFavorite);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mealId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;

    final meal = dummyMeals.firstWhere((meal) => meal.id == mealId);

    AppBar appBar = AppBar(
      title: Text(meal.title),
    );

    Widget _buildTitle(String title) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget _buildContainer(Widget child) {
      return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
        height: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
        ),
        child: child,
      );
    }

    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);

    final contentSize = mediaQuery.size.height -
        mediaQuery.padding.top -
        appBar.preferredSize.height;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Image.network(
            meal.imageUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            height: contentSize * 0.4,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: contentSize * 0.6,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  _buildTitle('Ingreidants'),
                  _buildContainer(ListView(
                    children: meal.ingredients
                        .map(
                          (inData) => Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.amber,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                            child: Text(inData),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  )),
                  _buildTitle('Steps'),
                  _buildContainer(
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: meal.steps.length,
                      itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                child: Text('# ${index + 1}'),
                              ),
                              subtitle: Text(meal.steps[index]),
                            ),
                            const Divider(),
                          ],
                        );
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          toggleFavorite(mealId);
        },
        child: Icon(
          // Icons.star,
          isFavorite(mealId) ? Icons.star : Icons.star_border,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I also find some this types of error on this site but I didn't figured it out why this happened so why this error showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using positional constructurctor, this makes consfusion on `MealDeatialRoute` consturctor.

You are reading like

```
MealDeatialRoute(this.isFavorite, this.toggleFavorite);
```

But on _AppState, passing on wrong order.

```dart
 MealDeatialRoute.routeName: (context) =>
            MealDeatialRoute(_toggleFavorite, _isMealFavorite),
```

Which will be

```dart
MealDeatialRoute(_isMealFavorite, _toggleFavorite),
```

To avoid this error in the future, try using named constructor.

Comment: Okk!! I am so dumb at this point, thanks for correction in my code. After this I will use name constructor instead of normal constructor. Once again Thank you. :)

Comment: Sometimes happen to all. Glad to help. You can find more about [constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors)